# Ansible: error: generator object is not iterable , list filter does not work. | for | task: remove certain elements from a list

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a list of hosts to decommission.
I struggle how to create a new list from the existing list test_decom_list.

I am completely open to do this in a better way or more Ansible or more efficient way.
For now just any method or obvious pointing in the right direction would be welcome.

```yaml
test_decom_list:
  - vm1
  - vm2
  - vm3
  - vm4
```

playbook:

```yaml
- name: check/power(on/off) hosts on vsphere and check non existing vm
  hosts: test
  ignore_errors: True
  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        vm: "{{ test_decom_list |select('match', '[a-z0-9]+[0-9]{2}\\.lx') | list}}"
        cacheable: True

    - name: check hosts on vsphere with domain name
      vmware_guest_info:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        name: "{{ item }}"
        schema: vsphere
        datacenter: Datacenter1
        properties: runtime.powerState
        validate_certs: False
      loop: "{{  vm }}" 
      register: vm_fact_dom
```

output:

```yaml
   "vm_fact_dom": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "instance": {
                    "runtime": {
                        "powerState": "poweredOff"
                    }
                },
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "datacenter": "Datacenter1",
                        "folder": null,
                        "hostname": "vm101",
                        "moid": null,
                        "name": "vm1",
                        "name_match": "first",
                        "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                        "port": 443,
                        "properties": [
                            "runtime.powerState"
                        ],
                        "proxy_host": null,
                        "proxy_port": null,
                        "schema": "vsphere",
                        "tags": false,
                        "use_instance_uuid": false,
                        "username": "user1",
                        "uuid": null,
                        "validate_certs": false
                    }
                },
                "item": "vm1"
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "instance": {
                    "runtime": {
                        "powerState": "poweredOff"
                    }
                },
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "datacenter": "Datacenter1",
                        "folder": null,
                        "hostname": "vm101",
                        "moid": null,
                        "name": "vm2",
                        "name_match": "first",
                        "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                        "port": 443,
                        "properties": [
                            "runtime.powerState"
                        ],
                        "proxy_host": null,
                        "proxy_port": null,
                        "schema": "vsphere",
                        "tags": false,
                        "use_instance_uuid": false,
                        "username": "user1",
                        "uuid": null,
                        "validate_certs": false
                    }
                },
                "item": "vm2"
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": true,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "datacenter": "Datacenter1",
                        "folder": null,
                        "hostname": "vm101",
                        "moid": null,
                        "name": "vm3",
                        "name_match": "first",
                        "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                        "port": 443,
                        "properties": [
                            "runtime.powerState"
                        ],
                        "proxy_host": null,
                        "proxy_port": null,
                        "schema": "vsphere",
                        "tags": false,
                        "use_instance_uuid": false,
                        "username": "user1",
                        "uuid": null,
                        "validate_certs": false
                    }
                },
                "item": "vm3",
                "msg": "Unable to gather information for non-existing VM vm3"
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": true,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "datacenter": "Datacenter1",
                        "folder": null,
                        "hostname": "vm101",
                        "moid": null,
                        "name": "vm4",
                        "name_match": "first",
                        "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                        "port": 443,
                        "properties": [
                            "runtime.powerState"
                        ],
                        "proxy_host": null,
                        "proxy_port": null,
                        "schema": "vsphere",
                        "tags": false,
                        "use_instance_uuid": false,
                        "username": "user1",
                        "uuid": null,
                        "validate_certs": false
                    }
                },
                "item": "vm4",
                "msg": "Unable to gather information for non-existing VM vm4"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

When the output contains `"msg": "Unable to gather information for non-existing VM vm3"`, i need to clean the list in order to continue with the process.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        reslt: "{{ vm_fact_dom.results|flatten }}"
        messg: "{{  vm_fact_dom.results|flatten|map(attribute='msg') | list }}"
        cacheable: True

    - set_fact:    
        missvm: "{{  reslt | selectattr('msg', 'defined') | map(attribute='item') | list }}"
        cacheable: True

    - set_fact:
        new_vm: "{{ vm |default(none)| reject('match', missvm ) }}"
        cacheable: True

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ missvm }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ new_vm }}"
```

output:

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************ok: [myvm] => {
    "msg": [
        "vm3",
        "vm4"
    ]
}

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************ok: [myvm] => {
    "msg": "<generator object select_or_reject at 0x7f5b6b2d1200>"
}
```

From the docs select/reject always creates a generator object which then needs filter list to be iterable. If i add `|list` to

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        new_vm: "{{ vm |default(none)| reject('match', missvm ) | list }}"
        cacheable: True
```

output:

```yaml
TASK [debug] 
fatal: []: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ vm |default(none)| reject('match', 
missvm ) | list }}): unhashable type: 'list'"}
...ignoring
```

I tried also without default.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ vm | reject('match', missvm ) | list }}"
```

output:

```yaml
TASK [debug] 
fatal: []: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ vm | reject('match', missvm ) | list }}): unhashable type: 'list'"}
...ignoring
```

Tried to add qmissvm and then replace missvm by qmissvm in set_fact: new_vm:

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        qmissvm: "{{ q('list', missvm) }}"
        cacheable: True
```

What i need is to get the new_vm list minus the two non exisitng vm's vm3 and vm4:

```yaml
new_vm:
  - vm1
  - vm2
```

Comment: As a start, the fact you have to add `list` as filter to your expression means that you are using ansible 2.9 or lower. Ansible 2.9 has been deprecated for almost 3 years now. Please use a supported version (i.e >= 2.12, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html#ansible-core-changelogs). Just to anticipate a possible "I can't upgrade" comment, Ansible only supported installation method is now through pip which makes it possible to install as a user and eventually in multiple versions through virtualenvs.

Comment: We're on supported version 2.12 or slightly higher . The rest of the infra is not in a virtualenv so what use would it have me to work in my virtualenv on the latest version whilst the rest of the infra is not? There would be incompatibility problems for sure, i would guess? Does anyone has any experience with this?

Comment: Well then the `list` filter is unneeded and if you get a generator back when debugging a var, something is wrong with the vars before. You have to debug further.

Comment: After some checking, i was missing this bit `reject('match', '(' + missvm | join('|') + ')')` which i found in this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62701036/filter-out-elements-from-list-if-matching-multiple-patterns) credits to @Zeitounator

Comment: The actual error was indeed before the error mentioned in the title of the original question. 
`fatal: [myvm]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ vm |default(none)| reject('match', missvm ) | list }}): unhashable type: 'list'"}`